# Referencing "unpublished" works

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, riemann-zeta

On arXiv I found [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9812143v1.pdf), the subject of which I am interested in. It was submitted to arXiv on 24 Dec 1998, so some years ago. However, I cannot find this publication in any journal from this date onwards. So, what is the credibility of this paper? I realise I could work through it properly and form my own opinion, but who cares about my opinion, especially if I were to reference it. Is it okay to reference a paper on arXiv even when it has not been published in a journal?

Comment: Yes it is fine.

Comment: Why is it fine to reference it? I have been indoctrinated to believe that a source should be credible. Is arXiv credible? I think I've seen/heard of papers on there with incorrect proofs. Not to doubt the content of the mentioned publication, but referencing such a repository goes against my better judgement. That's just the way I was taught when I was at University many years ago.

Comment: In general it is fine to cite papers on arXiv, especially if there is no alternative. Of course one needs to be a bit more careful if one uses specific claims, as these may not have been checked as thoroughly as for papers publishez in journals.

Comment: You probably don't know how corrupt/useless/damaging this peer review process is sometimes @Algorist.

Comment: Having published and peer reviewed papers in the past, I have some experience ! But I have no maths publications (yet) and so am not used to using the arXiv. In the past I've just submitted direct to a conference or journal and been accepted (or rejected :-) !)

Comment: What subject have you published in then? I would have guessed CS, but there arXiv is also quite common.

Comment: @msm Given you profile here I must express my doubt that you have much experience with this yourself.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft It is fine! I shall express that I don't care. I prefere leave you in your doubts... You have been 6 years here and earn 14K. I have been three months now. You do the math.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Yes, CS related, mainly algorithms/systems development for robotics, artificial intelligence, augmented reality.

Answer (score 0):

I was not aware until just now, but [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/41141/should-i-not-cite-an-arxiv-org-paper) is a pretty good discussion on Math Overflow.